# How to ignore a specific migration?

Tags: django, django-migrations

I have a migration like this:

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('app', '0020_auto_20191023_2245'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='agenda',
            name='theme',
            field=models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1),
        ),
    ]
```

But it raises an error:

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: column "theme" of relation "app_agenda" already exists
```

Not a problem, I've wrapped this error like this:

```
from django.db import migrations, models, ProgrammingError


def add_field_theme_to_agenda(apps, schema_editor):
    try:
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='agenda',
            name='theme',
            field=models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1),
        ),
    except ProgrammingError as e:  # sometimes it can exist
        if "already exists" not in str(e):
            raise


class Migration(migrations.Migration):
    dependencies = [
        ('app', '0020_auto_20191023_2245'),
    ]
    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(add_field_theme_to_agenda),
    ]
```

This works like a charm and all the following migrations are done.

My problem is that each time I run a "`makemigrations`" Django adds *again* the migration (= the one on the top of my question). I guess it's because it doesn't see it in the migrations, because my code obfuscate it.

How to circumvent this using migrations (dont say answers like "this problem is on your database, correct your database")?

Comment: Maybe you could run  migrate --fake  your_migration

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Django is re-creating the migrations because as you are doing the operation manually inside a RunPython operation, it can not understand the field is added. What you can try is (haven't tried this myself), subclass AddField operations to create a custom AddField operation, where you can handle the exception. Something like the following could work:

```
from django.db import migrations, models, ProgrammingError


class AddFieldIfNotExists(migrations.AddField):

    def database_forwards(self, app_label, schema_editor, from_state, to_state):
        try:
            super().database_forwards(app_label, schema_editor, from_state,
                                      to_state)
        except ProgrammingError as e:  # sometimes it can exist
            if "already exists" not in str(e):
                raise


class Migration(migrations.Migration):
    atomic = False
    dependencies = [
        ('app', '0070_auto_20191023_1203'),
    ]

    operations = [
        AddFieldIfNotExists(
            model_name='agenda',
            name='theme',
            field=models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1),
        ),
    ]
```

Comment: That's an excellent suggestion but it doesn't work with the error `django.db.utils.InternalError: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block`. I'll try to make it work then edit your answer + check it as valid if you don't mind (if I ever find the solution).

Comment: Hmm possibly you can overcome this by tweaking how you handle the exception, maybe cathing the exception at a higher level might work (it is possible the migration engine might need to catch that ProgrammingError somewhere else).

Comment: @OlivierPons sure, I'd be glad to see the full solution in this path as well.

Comment: Even if I do a "global" `try/except Exception` to catch them all, I still get `django.db.utils.InternalError: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block`

Comment: Done! **`\o/`** Thanks a lot. The problem was because it was checking after each operation (only one here!) that everything went fine. The solution was to add `atomic = False` (see my modifications of your own answer). Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

You can take advantage of the `--fake` flag in your migrate command

`./manage.py migrate app_name migration_number --fake`

This will mark the migration as done.

Comment: Even if it's done it's not actually solved... I mean my system could allow to make a whole bunch of migration even if mine (in the middle) is a problem (= doesn't create if it exists). The main objective is to always run everything in one row = "`migrate` everything" without the need to do a `--fake` specifically for this migration. (It's for docker...)

Comment: If you want to migration to run with a "standard" migrate command, convert it to a custom one with no actions inside, set your `add_field_theme_to_agenda` function with just a `pass` statement and will always run ok